# FORM with POST method request a refresh clicking back button

Tags: php, forms, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent browser waring when you hit the ‘go back’ button after form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687083/prevent-browser-waring-when-you-hit-the-go-back-button-after-form-submit)

How can i avoid the refreshing error message of the browser when the user click the back button after he submitted a form with method POST?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687083/prevent-browser-waring-when-you-hit-the-go-back-button-after-form-submit?rq=1

Comment: I don't think this is a dup. The linked question doesn't explain anything about PRG, because "I know about PRG, but I don't understand how to do it" is part of the question. So referring people from this question to that is not very useful.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

1. Submit form to form handler
2. Process data with form handler
3. Have form handler return a redirect response not an OK response
4. Display page after the redirect

If the user clicks back, they'll skip the form handler page (because it redirected), so they won't be resubmitting the form and won't get the warning.